# Xamarin.Forms Custom WebViews inside a ListView with calculated height per row

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, webview

I have a ListView and inside each row I want to place a custom HTMLWebView. As these WebViews differ in height depending on the content inserted, I want the height to be calculated and applied to each individual WebView.

If I place the WebViews inside a Grid, it works. But if I place the WebViews in a ListView the height is only calculated for the last row and I don't understand why.

All code can be found here:
https://github.com/SlimboTimbo/MultiWebviews

```
<ListView x:Name="lstView" HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <custom:HybridWebView Grid.Row="0" messageContent="{ Binding.Name}" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the height of **ViewCell** in runtime . You should call `cell.ForceUpdateSize();` to update the cell's size .

#### in Custom Renderer

```
 if (_xwebView != null)
{
    view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    await Task.Delay(100);
    string result = await _xwebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("(function(){return document.body.scrollHeight;})()");

    _xwebView.HeightRequest = Convert.ToDouble(result);

    MessagingCenter.Send<Object, double>(this, "LoadFinished", Convert.ToDouble(result));

}
```

#### in HybridWebView

```
   public HybridWebView()
    {

        Source = "";
        this.PropertyChanged += HybridWebView_PropertyChanged;

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, double>(this, "LoadFinished", (args, height) =>
        {


            var parent = this.Parent;
            while (parent != null && !(parent is ViewCell))
            {
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }
            if (parent is ViewCell cell)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    this.HeightRequest = height;
                    cell.ForceUpdateSize();
                });
            }

        });

    }
```

## Update

#### in Custom Renderer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

using WebView = Android.Webkit.WebView;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

using MultiWebviews.Controls;
using MultiWebviews.Droid.Renderers;
using Android.Webkit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MultiWebviews.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {

        public static int _webViewHeight;
        HybridWebView _xwebView = null;
        WebView _webView;
        Context _context;
        public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }



        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            }



            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            _xwebView = e.NewElement as HybridWebView;
            _webView = Control;

            Control.SetWebViewClient(new HybridWebViewClient(_xwebView));

        }

    }



    public class HybridWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        WebView _webView;
        HybridWebView _xwebView = null;


        public HybridWebViewClient(HybridWebView webview)
        {
            _xwebView = webview;
        }

        public async override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
        {
            try
            {
                _webView = view;
                if (_xwebView != null)
                {
                    view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    string result = await _xwebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("(function(){return document.body.scrollHeight;})()");

                    _xwebView.HeightRequest = Convert.ToDouble(result);




                    MessagingCenter.Send<Object, PassModel>(this, "LoadFinished", new PassModel(_xwebView.Id, Convert.ToDouble(result)));

                }
                base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### in HybridWebView

Add the bindable property **Id**

```
using System;


using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MultiWebviews.Controls
{


    public class HybridWebView : WebView
    {

        bool LoadFinish;

        public static readonly BindableProperty IdProperty =
          BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Id), typeof(string), typeof(HybridWebView), string.Empty);

        public string Id
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(IdProperty).ToString(); }
            set { 
                SetValue(IdProperty, value); 
            }
        }

        Action<string> action;

        public static readonly BindableProperty messageContentProperty =
          BindableProperty.Create(nameof(messageContent), typeof(string), typeof(HybridWebView), string.Empty);

        public string messageContent
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(messageContentProperty).ToString(); }
            set { 
                SetValue(messageContentProperty, value); 
            }
        }

        public void Cleanup()
        {
            action = null;
        }

        public void InvokeAction(string data)
        {
            if (action == null || data == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            action.Invoke(data);
        }


        public HybridWebView()
        {

            Source = "";
            this.PropertyChanged += HybridWebView_PropertyChanged;

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, PassModel>(this, "LoadFinished", (args, obj) =>
            {
                var id = obj.Id;

                var model = obj as PassModel;

                if(model.Id ==this.Id&&!LoadFinish)
                {
                    LoadFinish = true;
                    var parent = this.Parent;
                    while (parent != null && !(parent is ViewCell))
                    {
                        parent = parent.Parent;
                    }
                    if (parent is ViewCell cell)
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            this.HeightRequest = model.Height;
                            cell.ForceUpdateSize();
                        });
                    }
                }



            });

        }

        private void HybridWebView_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(messageContent)))
            {
                var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
                htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
                                    <head>
                                    <link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""chatmessage-content.css"">
                                    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'>
                                    </head>
                                    <body style=""background-color: #DDDDDD;"">
                                        <a class=""btn btn-true"" onclick=""setresponseandsubmit('1ca15124-9624-431e-8644-22a5839b7a10')"">test: </a>"
                                        + messageContent + 
                                        "<p>Extra line</p><p>Extra line</p><p>Extra line</p><p>Extra line</p><p>Extra line</p><p>Extra line</p><p>Extra line</p><p>Extra line</p><p>Extra line</p><p>Extra line</p>" +
                                    "</body></html>";
                Source = htmlSource;




            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### in xaml

```
<custom:HybridWebView Id="{Binding Id}" Grid.Row="1" messageContent="{ Binding Name}" />
```

#### in code behind

Make sure each Id is different .

```
pages = new ObservableCollection<PageViewModel>();
pages.Add(new PageViewModel{ Id = "0",  Name ="Test 1" });
pages.Add(new PageViewModel{ Id ="1" ,Name = "Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 " });
pages.Add(new PageViewModel { Id = "2", Name ="Test 3" });
pages.Add(new PageViewModel { Id = "3" ,Name = "Test 4 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 " });

lstView.ItemsSource = pages;
```

And add a new class in Forms project  to pass value in MessageingCenter .

```
public class PassModel
    {
        public string Id { get; private set; }
        public double  Height { get; private set; }

        public  PassModel(string id, double height)
        {
            Id = id;
            Height = height;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This seems to almost do what I want - while this does calculate a height, it seemingly gives all viewcells the height of the last cell. I have updated my github to show you what it does. 

If I add a breakpoint at the MessagingCenter in OnPageFinished, it will run over it exact to the amount of viewcells (in my demo four times) but the height (result) will always be the value of the LAST ViewCell (in this case 72).

But I will look into it more and see if I can figure it out (unless you can point me in the right direction).

Comment: That because of you set the `_xwebView` as static! So it will always the last one .

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much for going above and beyond with your extremely detailed answer.